# java File renameTo()

Tags: java, file, file-rename

first of all renameTo() works fine, the problem is after it has been renamed, the path of File f is still the old one instead of the new one, in other words File f is unusable, and has to be changed. but how should I do it?

```
    ArrayList<File> list = new ArrayList();
    public void myfunction() {
        // some code to fill list

        for (File f:list){
            changeName(f);
            System.out.println(f.getName());  // this print the old name
        }
    }

    public void changeName(File f){
    File newFile = new File(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(f.lastModified())+".txt");
        f.renameTo(newFile);
        f = newFile; //this line here doesn't work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because in JAVA variables are `passed by value`. If you want to see new content then return `newFile`, instead of `f = newFile;` statement.

Comment: @user2760830 lol.. That is the only answer, upto my knowledge, even if you disagree. BTW, you might want to accept answer so that others are benefited :)

Answer (score 3):

A `File` instance is not a file handle. It is

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

So changing the name of a file (in the system) does not change any `File` that was used to acces it.

Return a new `File` instance from your `changeName` method.

```
import java.io.File;

public class SOPlayground {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File before = new File("/tmp/before");
        File after = new File("/tmp/after");
        boolean success = before.renameTo(after);
        if (success) {
            before = after;
        }
        System.out.println(before);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/tmp/after
```

Comment: is there a way to change the private variable File.path?

Comment: It is `private` for a reason.